# Using variables in ADO Pipelines while using shared YAML files

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a YAML file that process the output of two different pipelines. We successfully have that pipeline working. Now I would like to create another pipeline using the same YAML file, but using variables specific to each pipeline.  I am trying to run one pipeline using the output of "develop" branch pipelines. Then a second pipeline that will use the output of "master/main" branch pipelines.  I saw parameters, but I do not want people to have to remember to select 'develop' or 'main' when these are run.
When I created the 'master' pipeline, I see a button to create variable in the ADO UI. I thought those would be specific to the pipeline and not the underlying YAML file.  I have tried various formats for the variables ${{ variables.branch }} and $(branch) .
Something like:

```
resources:
```

pipelines:

- pipeline: xyzBuild        # Name of the pipeline resource.

  source: $(xyzLinux_Pipeline) # The name of the pipeline referenced by this pipeline resource.

  trigger: true # Run this pipeline when any run of Build_xyz_MasterBranch completes

So, I would set xyz_Pipeline to the names of the pipelines in the specific pipeline.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding variables completely...
Sorry for the formatting... Cannot get the text to look like I want....
Thanks.

Edit: I see some Microsoft examples that have [image]
Which looks like it will trigger for either the 'master' or 'releases/*', in my case I could use 'develop'. But how does the checkout 'know' which repo to pull the code from ?

```
#   Update the local develop branch from the head of the remote repo.
- script: |
    git checkout develop
    git pull
  displayName: 'Pull the develop branch from the remote repo.'
```

our YAML files have the branch name hardcoded. Is there some special keyword that I can use that will specify the correct repo based on the trigger name?  We have only started to use these pipelines and we're all just guessing. I have looked at the ADO website, but it seems too fragmented for me to piece together the whole concept.

Comment: Why do you have different pipelines for different branches? You can use a single pipeline for different branches, with template expressions to change the behavior based on the branch.

Comment: @DanielMann do you have a link to a sample?  I did accomplish the build process for different branches using the same YAML file, but different piplines.  But the pipeline that is trying to combine the output of two different pipelines (of different repos) is the one that does not seem to accept variables.  We know nothing about pipelines, so are probably doing many things wrong.